# What OOD design pattern should be used for a server-handle-client request ?

Tags: c++, c, design-patterns, client-server

What OOD design pattern should be used for a server-handle-client request ?

I suggest message exchange pattern which allows the interchange of information (i.e. messages) between components and applications.

a message exchange pattern (MEP) describes the pattern of messages required by a communications protocol to establish or use a communication channel. There are two major message exchange patterns — a request-response pattern, and a one-way pattern. For example, the HTTP is a request-response pattern protocol, and the UDP has a one-way pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messaging_pattern

Am I right ? better ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, I think that if you're in doubt which pattern to use, it's best to solve the problem first and then decide afterwards which pattern best describes the solution, see if that realisation allows you to clean it up at all. Starting from a design pattern is great when you know that the pattern solves the problem, but if you aren't sure then you're just constraining yourself to solutions for other problems that quite possibly aren't yours. It's hard to imagine a server-client interaction that couldn't loosely be described as a message exchange pattern, so that label adds nothing.

Comment: +1 to Steve. Design By Patterns Considered Harmful.

Comment: I agree with you. But, before I begin to do coding, I have to have a basic framework about how to solve the problem. That is which pattern can help me solve it. right ?

Answer (score 1):

Being very familiar with client-server applications over UDP, I usually use the observer pattern which is very useful when receiving packets from the network. Whenever a packet comes from a remote machine, the socket takes the message and broadcasts it to all its listeners. The listeners will then do whatever they want with the data received as shown in the example below

```
public class MySocket {
   private socket rawSocket;
   private List<Listeners> dataListeners;
   //.. Initialization
   // This method gets called when data is received
   public receive(byte[] data){
       for(Listener listener : dataListeners) listener.processMessage(data);
   }
   public registerListener(Listener listener){
       dataListeners.add(listener);
   }
   public unRegisterListener(Listener listener){
       dataListeners.remove(listener);
   }
}
// Interface listener to be implemented by whoever want to receive data from a socket
public interface Listener{
   // Method to be implemented by any listener interested in receiving data
   void ProcessMessage(byte[] data);
}
public class MyListener implements Listener{
   @Override
   public void processMessage(byte[] data){
      // Do something with data...
   }
}
// All bits put together
MySocket mySocket = new MySocket();
socket.registerListener(new MyListener());
// Class MyListener can now receive everything that comes from a remote machine through the socket "mySocket"
```

I hope this helps,
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Whether you want to use UDP (one way), HTTP (stateless request-response) or some mechanism depends on the behavior of your application. Where real-time kind of messaging is required (like in algorithmic trading) UDP is the first choice where time of sending data packets become more important reliability of data packets. HTTP is the way to go for the web-applications.
However these are all protocols for message passing protocols. On application level here are my thoughts. In client-server application generally there are many clients who try to access the same server. So your server application should be capable of responding to multiple clients in parallel. So on application level your should maintain a [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern), and each client request should be handled in a thread from thread pool. Read the link to see more on benefits of using thread pool instead of creating threads for each client request.